# Django sort objects with foreign key case insensitive

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset

I'm trying to sort a query according to a foreign key field case insensitive. 
My models are:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, default = User)
trade_option = models.CharField(max_length= 10)

class Book(models.Model):
book_title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

I want to sort my post objects according to the book_title field case insensitive.

I know if I want to sort case insensitive with the fields in Class Post I can just do:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(trade_option= 'buy').extra(select = 
    {'lower_name' : 'lower( title )'}).order_by('lower_name')
```

However, when I try the same technique with sorting with foreign key book with book_title:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(trade_option= 'buy').extra(select = 
    {'lower_name' : 'lower( book__book_title )'}).order_by('lower_name')
```

I get the error "no such column: book__boot_title"

I would like to know where I'm doing this wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A related lookup like `book__book_title` only works in the context of Django. Anything in `extra` is not processed by Django, so these lookups won't work. You have to explicitly fetch the result from the related table.

Please note that the ordering you're trying to define is most likely not what you expect it to be: a `Post` object can have multiple related `Book` objects. Ordering by `book__book_title` (manually or through the orm) can give you either an indeterminate ordering or duplicate rows, depending on the exact details of your query. You need to define which related `book_title` the posts should be ordered by.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here's what you should do:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

posts = Post.objects.filter(trade_option= 'buy').order_by(Lower('title'))
```

Comment: Good answer, but keep in mind this is new in Django 1.8